# Ubuntu 20.04 is freezing so often

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, kernel, hardware

MY ubuntu 20.04 is freezing so often and I have to hard restart it, whenever it happens is there any known issue that could be a reason for that? I have taken some screenshot of my logs

I'm running my ubuntu on Acer Helios 300 core i7th 10gen, RTX 2060, SSD nvme2

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpzYf.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrL08.png)

[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTGf2.png)
[screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKNNk.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text always include text in the body of the question if you want everyone to see them.

Comment: there is no option to copy it from logs app

Comment: cut and paste with keyboard keys ctrl c and v